# How to keep a cron job running without break

Tags: cron

I have a cron job to be run every 5 minutes, and I found the cron job will be stopped at around 2 minutes from the start.
[image: cron job output]

The cron job will query a batch of records and update them with some external API calls. Below is the log I make when running the cron job. You should find there are 7 records to be queried, but after it ran the 5th record then, it stopped.

The first 3 lines are the log from the previous cron job, this cron job was started at 14:04, till 15:48, it stopped and then retried again, but no further action.

```
2023-07-21 23:56:31 'CronJob Order payment successful Uprise: 25694'
2023-07-21 23:56:31 'Completed batch payment at 2023-07-21 23:56:31'
2023-07-21 23:56:31 'Total time used: 00:00:27'
2023-07-22 00:14:04 '--------------------------------------------------'
2023-07-22 00:14:04 'Start batch payment at 2023-07-22 00:14:04'
2023-07-22 00:14:04 'Cron job called by /cron/daily_cron.php via IP 109.106.254.213'
2023-07-22 00:14:04 '--- Query result ---'
2023-07-22 00:14:04 'Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object 20887
    [1] => WP_Post Object 20350
    [2] => WP_Post Object 19822
    [3] => WP_Post Object 15828
    [4] => WP_Post Object 10337
    [5] => WP_Post Object 10294
    [6] => WP_Post Object 9206
)
'
2023-07-22 00:14:09 'api call payment for order #25697'
2023-07-22 00:14:14 'api call response'
2023-07-22 00:14:32 'CronJob Order payment failed Uprise: 25697'
'
2023-07-22 00:14:37 'api call payment for order #25700'
2023-07-22 00:14:39 'api call response'
2023-07-22 00:14:55 'CronJob Order payment successful Uprise: 25700'
'
2023-07-22 00:14:59 'api call payment for order #25703'
2023-07-22 00:15:01 'api call response'
2023-07-22 00:15:17 'CronJob Order payment successful Uprise: 25703'
'
2023-07-22 00:15:21 'api call payment for order #25706'
2023-07-22 00:15:23 'api call response'
2023-07-22 00:15:41 'CronJob Order payment successful Uprise: 25706'
'
2023-07-22 00:15:45 'api call payment for order #25709'
2023-07-22 00:15:48 'api call response'
'
       cronjob break here without error
'
2023-07-22 00:16:06 '--------------------------------------------------'
2023-07-22 00:16:06 'Start batch payment at 2023-07-22 00:16:06'
2023-07-22 00:16:06 'Cron job called by /cron/daily_cron.php via IP 109.106.254.213'
2023-07-22 00:16:06 '--- Query result ---'
2023-07-22 00:16:06 'Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object 10294
    [1] => WP_Post Object 9206
)
'
```

Do anyone can help how I can solve the cron job break issue?

Comment: Cron job could be started periodically, such as at 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 0. However, if the cron job could not complete or terminate normally before the next start, it may interfere with the next run. Examples of interferences are writing to the same  file, writing to the same database table that does not allow concurrent access.

Comment: @yoonghm I got your meaning, but I want to know how I can avoid the termination. I am quite sure this termination was not caused accidentally. No matter if I set the periodic time at 10 or 30 mins, the corn job stops around 2 mins from the start.

Comment: You run the job manually ans monitor how it coukd be termianted5. Alternatively, put in traces in your script.